# Excel vba How to get combination of the numbers output into excel rows?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, mapping

I need to find out a way to output the result of all combinations of the numbers into rows ( best if could be in a single row)

I have 8 digits {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} the typical output for the combination is   i;j (i, j are numbers from the set and i< j)  if pick up two. To generate result is simple:

```
    Dim Myarray_2 As String
    Dim sht as Worksheet
    set sht = Sheet1

    Myarray_2 = ""          ' pick up 2 out of 8
    For j  = 2 To 8
        For i = 1 To j - 1
        sht.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = Str(MyArray(i)) + ";" + Str(MyArray(j))
            Myarray_2 = Myarray_2 + Str(MyArray(i)) + ";" + Str(MyArray(j)) + "|"
        Next i
    Next j
```

This is an example for pick up 2, I already have it output to rows of a worksheet.

I also have solution for picking up 3, now my questions is for the rest of the cases, how to get the out put?

Here is the solution for picking up 3:

```
    Dim Myarray_3 As String
        Myarray_3 = ""          ' 3 out of 8
    k = 3
    Do While k >= 3 And k <= 8
    'inner loop through i j
        For j = 2 To k - 1
            For i = 1 To j - 1
                sht.Cells(i + 11, j - 1 + m) = Str(MyArray(i)) + ";" + Str(MyArray(j)) + ";" + Str(MyArray(k))
                Myarray_3 = Myarray_3 + Str(MyArray(i)) + ";" + Str(MyArray(j)) + ";" + Str(MyArray(k)) + "|"
            Next i
        Next j

   k = k + 1
   m = m + 7
   Loop
```

By the way the MyArray(i) is initialized as Myarray(i) = i

Comment: Is `1,2` and `2,1` the same thing? If so, nested loops would do it.

Comment: i<j, so 2,1 is not allowed.

Comment: The first thing I would always say, is do your combinatorial work in an array. Then output the array at the end..

Answer (score 0):

I found some code that I got from another good programmer, I changed the code to fit to your problem. If you have N as the number of members of your set/array, then you will have (2^N)-1 combinations, however you can filter them using your own conditions. Note that in your problem, the order of the members would be important when it comes to filtration using your condition.

The code will first generate ALL OF THE COMBINATIONS and then apply the conditions. Array Result would be the main output so its size will be always (2^N)-1. Array Result-filtered will be what you want.

Note that if you have the numbers sorted from left to right, arrays Result and Result_filtered will be the same.

You can print the out put with any format you like into any sheet.

This method uses bitwise calculation to get the combinations:

if N=2, then number of comnibations would be (2^2)-1=3
we always exclude 0 'in binary of course
{A,B} -> { [00],[01],[10],[11] } ->{ ignore, [B],[A],[AB]}

I hope this helps! if it did, please hit the checkmark to this anwer

**Run Sub Test:**

```
Sub Test()
  Dim bCondSatisfied As Boolean
  Dim InxComb As Integer
  Dim InxResult As Integer
  Dim count As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim arr() As String
  Dim TestData() As Variant
  Dim Result() As Variant
  Dim Result_filtered() As Variant

  TestData = Array(1, 3, 2, 4)

  Call GenerateCombinations(TestData, Result)

  'Now you have all the possible combinations, you can apply custom conditions
  '(e.g. any number on the left side of another number should be smaller, practically this is satisfied with the
  ' given test array, but if the numbers are scrambled it will fix the problem)
  ReDim Result_filtered(0 To 0)
  Result_filtered(0) = "No Combination Matched the Condition" 'default for the case there is no result matched

  count = 0
  For i = 0 To UBound(Result)
        arr() = Result(i)
        bCondSatisfied = True
        If UBound(arr) > 0 Then 'if there is more than one number in the array, compare the adjacent numbers
            For j = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
              If arr(j) > arr(j + 1) Then
                bCondSatisfied = False
                Exit For
              End If
            Next j
        End If

        'Store the array in the filtered array if it passed the test
         If bCondSatisfied = True Then
           ReDim Preserve Result_filtered(count)
           Result_filtered(count) = arr
           count = count + 1
         End If
  Next i


  'Print Result
  For InxResult = 0 To UBound(Result)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & InxResult + 1, 3) & " ";
    For InxComb = 0 To UBound(Result(InxResult))
      Debug.Print "[" & Result(InxResult)(InxComb) & "] ";
    Next
    Debug.Print
  Next

  Debug.Print "-----------------" 'separate two results

  'Print Result_filtered
  For InxResult = 0 To UBound(Result_filtered)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & InxResult + 1, 3) & " ";
    For InxComb = 0 To UBound(Result_filtered(InxResult))
      Debug.Print "[" & Result_filtered(InxResult)(InxComb) & "] ";
    Next
    Debug.Print
  Next

End Sub

Sub GenerateCombinations(ByRef AllFields() As Variant, _
                                             ByRef Result() As Variant)

  Dim InxResultCrnt As Integer
  Dim InxField As Integer
  Dim InxResult As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim NumFields As Integer
  Dim Powers() As Integer
  Dim ResultCrnt() As String

  NumFields = UBound(AllFields) - LBound(AllFields) + 1

  ReDim Result(0 To 2 ^ NumFields - 2)  ' one entry per combination
  ReDim Powers(0 To NumFields - 1)          ' one entry per field name

  ' Generate powers used for extracting bits from InxResult
  For InxField = 0 To NumFields - 1
    Powers(InxField) = 2 ^ InxField
  Next

 For InxResult = 0 To 2 ^ NumFields - 2
    ' Size ResultCrnt to the max number of fields per combination
    ' Build this loop's combination in ResultCrnt
    ReDim ResultCrnt(0 To NumFields - 1)
    InxResultCrnt = -1
    For InxField = 0 To NumFields - 1
      If ((InxResult + 1) And Powers(InxField)) <> 0 Then
        ' This field required in this combination
        InxResultCrnt = InxResultCrnt + 1
        ResultCrnt(InxResultCrnt) = AllFields(InxField)
      End If
    Next
    ' Discard unused trailing entries
    ReDim Preserve ResultCrnt(0 To InxResultCrnt)
    ' Store this loop's combination in return array
    Result(InxResult) = ResultCrnt
  Next

End Sub
```